# Lua 4 to Lua 5.3 statement

Tags: lua

I found a Lua 4 script for text justification in this site: [http://lua-users.org/wiki/TextJustification][1]. I try re-write the script to  Lua 5.3 scripts.
Belows, which I don't know how to write in Lua 5.3 statement:

```
    if not arg or getn(arg) < 1 then
     MAX = DEFMAX
    else
     MAX = tonumber(arg[1])
     if not MAX or MAX < 0 then MAX = DEFMAX end
    end
```

and this part:

```
  _, n = gsub(line, "(%S+)", function (s) q_insert(%text, s) end)
```

How to re-write in Lua 5.3?

Comment: `getn(arg)` => `#arg`, `gsub` => `string.gsub`, `%text` => `text`

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff  - great!. Work properly